# Making Angular add X-XSRF-TOKEN header despite having not root cookie

Tags: angular, spring, cookies, http-headers, csrf

In our application (frontend is in angular, backend in java) there's the problem of not adding the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header on a request, resulting in backend returning 403 (forbidden).

The xsrf mechanism is implemented through cookies with the help of spring's security [CsrfTokenRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenRepository.html)

The `saveToken()` method adds a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` to the response with the following properties:

1. Path = "/forum-rest"
2. httpOnly property = false

And it results in backend returning 403:

`Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter ' _csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'`

I did some research and found the following question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510998/angular-6-does-not-add-x-xsrf-token-header-to-http-request). After applying the solution (changing the path of the cookie to "/") to the app the problem's gone. Now, the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header is always present and the app can proceed.

However, I need to set this cookie's path only to **"/forum-rest"** and not the root of the app.
I tried to add the header based on a cookie in angular not to no avail (the cookie is null on frontend).

**How do I make angular add the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header with the cookie path being "/forum-rest" and not "/"?**

The angular's version is AngularJS 1.5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465726/angular-5-xsrf-token-cookie-and-x-xsrf-header-are-not-same